# How to spy on properties returned from mocked file

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, spy

Using Jest, I would like to mock one of my dependencies, but I would like to spy on the properties that mock is returning. For example, something like:

```js
const mockGet = jest.fn(() => {});
const mockPost = jest.fn(() => {});
const mockDel = jest.fn(() => {});

jest.mock('../../services/MyService', () => {
  return {
    mockGet,
    mockPost,
    mockDel
  };
});

// ...

describe('MyService', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    myService.doThis();
    expect(mockGet).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

The problem is this gives an error `jest.mock() is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.`

The only way I can get it to work so far is by defining the mocks inside the call to `jest.mock`:

```
jest.mock('../../services/MyService', () => {
  return {
    mockGet: jest.fn(() => {}),
    mockPost: jest.fn(() => {}),
    mockDel: jest.fn(() => {})
  };
});
```

But then how do I access the properties to see if they were called?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`Service.ts`:

```js
class Service {
  public get() {
    return 'real data';
  }
  public post() {}
  public del() {}
  public doThis() {
    console.log('real do this');
    return this.get();
  }
}
export { Service };
```

`Service.spec.ts`:

```js
import { Service } from './service';

const service = new Service();
// console.log(service);

jest.mock('./service.ts', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('./service.ts');
  const { Service: OriginalService } = originalModule;

  const ServiceMocked = {
    ...OriginalService.prototype,
    get: jest.fn(),
    post: jest.fn(),
    del: jest.fn()
  };

  return {
    Service: jest.fn(() => ServiceMocked)
  };
});

describe('Service', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    service.get = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce('mocked data');
    const actualValue = service.doThis();
    expect(actualValue).toBe('mocked data');
    expect(service.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57172774/service.spec.ts
  Service
    ✓ should do something (11ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/57172774/service.ts:6
    real do this

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.336s, estimated 3s
```